# Multi-line and spanned headers with Pandas (python)

Tags: python, pandas

I need to draw a table as shown in image.
I'm facing several problems:

1. How can I define headers with severel lines?
2. How can I span (enlarge/merge) header cells [0,3] to [0,6]?
3. How can I apply background color to a cell?

[image]

I've tried the following:

```
import pandas as pd

headers0 = ['',     '',      '',          '7 dies', '...',   '...',    '...']
headers1 = ['',     'Màxim', 'Mitjana',   '',       '',      '',       'Balanç']
headers2 = ['Lloc', 'diari', '(30 dies)', 'Consum', 'Màxim', 'Balanç', '%']
...
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([headers0,headers1,headers2])
```

Problem 1. is solved, but columns are not spanned (problem 2.)
I don't how to do 3.

Comment: are you really trying to export to Excel or OpenDocument format? there's not enough information here to know how you're representing the Pandas output

Comment: Nope, I've designed an example of what I want in LibreOffice, and now I want to generate it with Pandas

Answer (score 1):

To get multiple headers you can use this boiler plate code and adapt to your needs:

note that this method is relatively easy as the headers are just a list of tuples.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create a list of tuples representing the column headers
headers = [("Group A", "Feature 1"), 
           ("Group A", "Feature 2"), 
           ("Group B", "Feature 1"), 
           ("Group B", "Feature 2")]

# Create a random 2D array of data
data = np.random.randn(5, 4)

# Create a DataFrame with multi-index column headers
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(headers))

# Print the DataFrame
print(df)
```

The output of the above looks like this:

```
    Group A             Group B          
  Feature 1 Feature 2 Feature 1 Feature 2
0  1.070639  0.032569  0.452355  0.044998
1  0.331957  0.055572 -0.643516 -0.257413
2  1.888934 -0.307388  1.742004  0.395956
3  1.448742 -0.807641 -0.116213 -0.884502
4  0.115313  1.002843 -0.017316 -1.136110
```

Comment: Great! That works perfectly to solve 1. (multi-line) and 2. (span). In addition, makes code much easy to understand when defining the headers. Still need to solve 3. (colors)